# Continuity of $f$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Could you please help me the following question from Adam's Calculus?

> Let
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x,   & \text{if } x=1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots \\
> x^2, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Is it continuous at $x=0$?

According to the definition of continuity, it's not continuous at $x=1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$ At $x=0$ it is continuous, but I cannot understand how it is continuous at $x=0$ when the values of $f$ are approaching $0$ at two different rates. I mean, in any interval containing $x=0$ there are points at which the function is discontinuous. Is it enough to rely on the definition of continuity?

Comment: A function can be continuous at a point even if it has discontinuity point in every neighbourhood of this point (things can even be worse : a function can be continuous at only one point, and discontinuous in all other points !).

Comment: Take people gathering to a rendez-vous point. They are approaching at different speeds (running or walking for instance), but as long as nobody stops approaching or divert from the target, they all will converge to that point, no matter how fast/slow a single dude can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean property there exists a $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\epsilon>1/n$. Let $\delta=1/n$.

Now, let $|x|<\delta$ be arbitrary. If $x=1/m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$, then $|f(x)-f(0)|=1/m<1/n<\epsilon$.

Otherwise, $|f(x)-f(0)|=x^2\le |x|<\delta=1/n<\epsilon$.

Thus, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to note  that for $|x|<1$, you have
$$
|f(x)-0| \leq x \to 0, \quad x\to 0
$$
This implies that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0=f(0)$, and therefore $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution You are right, I just edited the post!

Comment: current version seems correct to me

Answer (score 2):

There is no “rate” of approaching. Nothing approaches anywhere.

The function is continuous at $a$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $|x-a|<\delta$, it holds $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

In your case, $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ is the inequality to prove.

We need that $1/n<\delta$ implies $1/n<\varepsilon$, so a first attempt is to choose $\delta=\varepsilon$. However, we also need that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|x^2|<\varepsilon$ for points not of the form $1/n$. OK, let's choose
$$
\delta=\min(\varepsilon,1)
$$
Now, if $1/n<\delta$, then $1/n=|f(1/n)|<\varepsilon$. For the other points,
$$
|f(x)|=|x^2|<|x|<\delta\le\varepsilon
$$
and we're done.